# Customize DrawerNavigator - ReactNative

Tags: android, ios, react-native, navigation-drawer, react-navigation

I have my side menu via DrawerNavigator. I know that to customize the drawer, it's in "contentComponents" props.

I want for example, put a button who open a modal like : Share (to share the app on other social media)

But for now, all my button are route. So if I click on it, it's redirect to the page (normal). I just want to add a button who react and not redirect.

I don't know how to custom that in the Component  dynamically. I think about hardcoded each button (some for redirect, some for display simple modal).

Here is my code :

**index.android.js**

```
const DrawerContent = (props) => (
<ScrollView>
    <View style={styles.container}>
        <Text style={styles.logo}>TechDico</Text>
        <Text style={{ paddingLeft: 10, paddingRight: 10, fontSize: 13, textAlign: 'center', color: '#f4f4f4' }}>Des millions de traductions classées par domaine d'activité</Text>
    </View>
    <DrawerItems style={{ marginTop: 30 }} {...props} />
</ScrollView>
)

const appNavigator = DrawerNavigator({
    Redirection1: {
        screen: Index,
        navigationOptions: {
            drawerLabel: 'Redirection1',
            drawerIcon: ({ tintColor }) => (<Icon name="home" size={20} color={tintColor} />),
        }
    },
    DisplayModal: {
        screen: Index,
        navigationOptions: {
            drawerLabel: 'DisplayModal',
            drawerIcon: ({ tintColor }) => (<Icon name="home" size={20} color={tintColor} />),
        }
    },
    Redirection2: {
        screen: Index,
        navigationOptions: {
            drawerLabel: 'Redirection2',
            drawerIcon: ({ tintColor }) => (<Icon name="home" size={20} color={tintColor} />),
        }
    }, }, {
        // define customComponent here
        contentComponent: DrawerContent,
        contentOptions: {
            inactiveTintColor: '#000000',
            activeTintColor: '#1eacff',
            showIcon: true,
        }
    });
```

**Index class**

```
export default class Index extends Component {
    renderRoot = () => {
        const { navigation } = this.props;

        console.log("My Navigation ", navigation);

        switch (navigation.state.key) {
            case 'Redirection1':
                return (
                    <App navigation={navigation} />
                );
            case 'DisplayModal':

// TODO I don't want to return so I can remove to cancel the redirection, but now, how can I display a modal without redirect. 
                return (
                    <DisplayModal navigation={navigation} />
                );
            case 'Redirection2':
                return (
                    <Redirection2 navigation={navigation} />
                );
            default:
                return (
                    <Test navigation={navigation} />
                );
        }
    }
```

I'm using 'react-navigation'.

Answer (score 2):

I'm looking at the same task as well. I think having multiple routes pointing to the same screen type may cause eventually a mess with state management, as each screen instance is different.

Looking at the source code in `DrawerSidebar`/`DrawerNavigatorItems` it seems all items in the sidebar list are those found in drawer's route config (unless we rewrite completely `DrawerNavigatorItems`). So maybe we may have a fake screen for some route and in `componentWillMount` implement required action and then navigate to the default route.

Here is a sample code:

```
let drawer = DrawerNavigator({
  Main: {
    screen: MainScreen,
  },
  About: {
    screen: AboutScreen,
  },
  ContactUs: {
    screen: ContactUsFakeScreen,
  },
});

const mailUrl = "mailto:test@test.com";

class ContactUsFakeScreen extends React.Component {
    componentWillMount() {
        let self = this;
        Linking.canOpenURL(mailUrl)
            .then(self.openEmail)
            .catch(err => self.openEmail(false));
    }

    openEmail(supported) {
        if (supported) {
            Linking.openURL(mailUrl).catch(err => {});
        }

        let { navigation } = this.props;
        navigation.navigate('Main');        
    }

    render() {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Here `Main`/`MainScreen` and `About`/`AboutScreen` are regular routes and screens, while `ContactUs`/`ContactUsFakeScreen` only pretend to be a route and a screen. Clicking on `ContactUs` will trigger `componentWillMount` which deals with email screen and then eventually navigates to the `MainScreen` (`Main` route).

Another approach could be to hijack `getStateForAction` from drawer router and put some extra routing logic there replacing destination route on the fly. Something along these lines:

```
    const defaultDrawerGetStateForAction = drawer.router.getStateForAction;

    drawer.router.getStateForAction = (action, state) => {
        let newState = defaultDrawerGetStateForAction(action, state);
        if (action.type === 'Navigation/NAVIGATE' && action.routeName === 'ContactUs') {
            // extra logic here ...
            newState.routes.forEach(r => {
                if (r.key === 'DrawerClose') {
                    // switching route from ContactUs to Main.
                    r.index = 0;
                }
            });
        }
        return newState;
    }
```

And if an item in the drawer list is not even actionable (like copyright), then fake screen will look even simpler (note styling via `navigationOptions`):

```
let drawer = DrawerNavigator({
    ...
    Copyright: {
        screen: Copyright,
    },
});

class Copyright extends React.Component {
    static navigationOptions = {
        drawerLabel: ({ tintColor, focused }) => 
                (<Text style={{color: '#999'}}>Copyright 2017</Text>)
            )

    };

    componentWillMount() {
        let { navigation } = this.props;
        navigation.navigate('Main');        
    }

    render() {
        return null;
    }
}
```